# Booting new version of OS X from old bootcamp windows version

Tags: windows, bootcamp, startup

I’ve got an old Macbook Pro 2012 with macOS Catalina on it. There is an old Win 7 installation with Bootcamp 4.1. I booted into it after a couple of years and now I can’t boot macOS. Pressing “Restart to OS X” just boots Windows again, there is no mac partition displayed in Windows Bootcamp (I suppose, it is because of apfs), also I have no access to efi password to get into boot menu. Is there any ways to boot macOS (even with losing all of windows data)?

Comment: You could try to see if Apple Software Update exists in Windows 7. If Apple Software Update exists, then you could try to see if there is an update to Boot Camp available to download and install. However, this is probably just a long shot.

Comment: Sadly, it is just a long shot. Updating everything doesn't help. But thank you anyway

Comment: Do you have access to any other computers? If so, what operating systems are installed?

Comment: I have an access to windows and linux operating systems, and also I have a usb stick with os x installation

Comment: Why is the Firmware Password an obstacle? Is this owned by a company, school, parent?

Comment: This macbook was a present, it was used by another person, he has set it, but he hasn’t remembered it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: From my understanding not knowing the Firmware Password is preventing access to the Mac Startup Manager (holding down the option key at startup). Windows 7 has an old version of BootCamp that can not recognize APFS. This is preventing the use of BootCamp to selecting Catalina as the default on startup from Windows 7.

Comment: Weline: Is the *"USB stick with OS X installation"* an installer or an actual installation of OS X. Also, which version of OS X?

Comment: @DavidAnderson - sure… but I wanted to know *why* the password isn't available. It's bypassable on a 2012, but I wanted to be happy about *why* before going down that path.

Comment: The USB stick has the latest version of Catalina (maybe, excluding some minor updates)

Comment: @Tetsujin: If you know way to bypass, then I will not post a rather complex possible answer involving rEFInd. Also, I wonder if Weline may have an USB macOS installer which Boot Camp may recognize. If so, then Boot Camp might be able to make the USB stick the default to boot. Once booted to the stick, Catalina might be made the default to boot. This all depends on what is on the stick.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - https://mac-optimization.bestreviews.net/bypassing-efi-lock-on-your-mac/ Take out 1 RAM stick, reset SMC, put RAM back.

Comment: Well, I tried, but it seems there is no removeable RAM sticks in my mac